# JetDrive 520 to M.2

Tags: ssd, compatibility, m.2

I have a Transcend SSD JetDrive 520 from my old Macbook. Now I bought the Asus Z170 Pro gaming motherboard with M.2 slot for SSD. Can I connect the JetDrive to this socket?

Comment: According to https://www.transcend-info.com/apple/jetdrive/ the jetdrives is a regular USB to SATA enclosure (albeith with M.2 interface). So yes, it should work, though the drive inside the jetdrive might be limited to SATA speeds rather than the much higher performance NVME options.  (Sadly I did not find anything on their site to indicate it it only did SATA or supported both SATA and MVME).

Answer (score 1):

[msata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Mini-SATA_.28mSATA.29) is a different interface from m.2, and apple used [a non standard](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6527754?start=0&tstart=0) pinout for it.

So, no, it almost certainly will not work.